# Want to run javascript code39.js to insert barcode into mailto

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating an email using mailto and I wish to insert a code 39 barcode using a Javscript routine code39.js, which runs fine on the screen page but does not in the email.

I have this inserted in the `head`

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/Javascript" src="code39.js></script>
```

In the email body I have:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="Text/Javascript">
    Code39(","",",50,0,"<?php echo $barcode; ?>",1); 
</script>
```

Nothing prints but the page seems happy with the code as the rest of the email appears in Outlook.

Am I trying to do the impossible?

Comment: In my (limited) experiene, email clients are a mess. I'd recommend against relying on JS within an email, since at least some recipients will read them from an environment in which JavaScript won't work. I'd recommend running the barcode insertion serverside if at all possible.

Comment: should generate the barcode as an image and attach to email, can never expect email clients to run active content (big vulnerability)

Comment: or you could call a URL to get the barcode, but that will very often be blocked as well (with good reason / prevent tracking)